# Expected value $E(XY)$ of dependent bivariate distribution?

Tags: statistics

**Two fair dice are thrown and
the number of times a 1 comes up is recorded as $X$ and the number of
times a 6 comes up is $Y$.
The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is shown in the following
table.
$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 &  &  & y\\
 &  & 0 & 1 & 2\\
 & 0 & \frac{16}{36} & \frac{8}{36} & \frac{1}{36}\\
x & 1 & \frac{8}{36} & \frac{2}{36} & 0\\
 & 2 & \frac{1}{36} & 0 & 0
\end{array}$}

**Calculate $E(XY)$**

Looking at the problem, the joint distribution does not look to be
independent since $ f_{X|Y}(x|y)\neq f_{X}(x).f_{Y}(y)$ for all
values

$x$ and $y$, given the fact it is not independent we cannot use the formulae
$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

How can the expected value be correctly calculated ?

Comment: Where does the value (34/36) come from in your solution?

Answer (score 1):

We have $XY=0$, unless $X=1$ and $Y=1$.  In that case, $XY=1$.

Thus $\Pr(XY=1)$, from the table, is $\frac{2}{36}$. And therefore $\Pr(XY=0)=\frac{34}{36}$. Now we know the complete distribution of $XY$, so we can find its expectation, which is $(0)\left(\frac{34}{36}\right)+(1)\left(\frac{2}{36}\right)$.

**Remark:** Computing $\Pr(XY=0)$ was unnecessary, since it would  later be multiplied by $0$. We did it to fit this computation into the standard expectation calculation framework.